# OpenGL es 2, Shaders not compiling

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm trying to make a very simple point light and I'm failing miserably. All I know is that my shaders doesn't compile correctly (I don't seem to get much error information).
My shaders are:

#### Vertex Shader Code

```
"uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;"
+ "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;"
+ "attribute vec4 a_Position;"
+ "varying vec3 v_Position;"
+ "void main() {"
+ "v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);"
+ "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * a_Position;" + "}";
```

#### Fragment Shader Code

```
"precision mediump float;"
+ "uniform vec3 u_LightPos;"
+ "varying vec3 v_Position;"
+ "uniform vec4 vColor;"
+ "void main() {"
+ "float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);"
+ "distance = 1.0 / distance;"
+ "distance = clamp(distance, 0.0, 1.0);"
+ "gl_FragColor = vColor * distance;" + "}";
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
P.S. I know very little about the opengl es shader syntax so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `uMVPMatrix` should be `u_MVMatrix`

Try to get a compile log when compiling shaders.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I feel dumb. It's compiling and I get a result, still doesn't look right but I can hopefully figure that out, thanks!